# ASP.NET / jQuery : post JSON to web-service

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, json, web-services

I'm trying to post some JSON to a web service. The web-service is executed but there's no data available.

The jQuery looks like this :

```
var json = {"Results": results};
var jsonArray=JSON.stringify(json);
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: requestURL,
    data: jsonArray ,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) { TCG.QUE.processSaveButtonSucceeded(data); },
    error: function (data) { TCG.QUE.processSaveButtonFailed(data); }
});
```

And the webservice implemented in a controller looks like this :

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]string value)
{
    object o1 = Request.Content;
    HttpResponseMessage r = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    return r;
}
```

If I take out the `[FromBody]` directive then I get a 404. If I leave it in the code is executed but the value of the `value` argument is null.

I thought the `[FromBody]` directive meant the data was contained in the Request object but if it is I can't find it .

Would appreciate any suggestions so that I can access the JSON from the client within the `Post` method.

---

UPDATE:

I just re-read this : http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api which made me wonder whether the name I was giving the JSON blog client side should correspond to the name of the argument on which the `[FromBody]` is applied so I changed the name of the argument from `value` to `Results` but still the value within the `Post` method is null.

---

RESOLUTION
After reading the blog post referred to by Prashanth Thurairatnam I changed my method to be like this and it works :

```
    public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]JToken jsonbody)
    {
        // Process the jsonbody 

        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Created);
    }
```

.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you are passing into `results`. Ran into [this blog](http://bizcoder.com/posting-raw-json-to-web-api). You may want to give it a go. The blog talks on passing the data as JSON object/ array (you may want to try without JSON.stringify)

Comment: YES ! Thanks very much. Just to summarise by using a using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken object as the argument to my method I then get a value in the method that I can make use of to extract the data from. There's more about Newtonsoft.Json here : http://www.newtonsoft.com/json . I'm about add the revised version of the method to the question for the benefit of those that come afterwards.